# Updating the scikit multinomial classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to update the scikit multinomial classifier with the new training data. Here is what i had tried

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Training with first training set
targets = ['education','film','sports','laptops','phones']
x = ["football is the sport","gravity is the movie", "education is imporatant","lenovo is a laptop","android phones"]
y = np.array([2,1,0,3,4])
clf = MultinomialNB()
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(stop_words='english', non_negative=True,
                                   n_features=32*2)
X_train = vectorizer.transform(x)
clf.partial_fit(X_train, y, classes=[0,1,2,3,4])

#Testing with First training set
test_data = ["android","lenovo","Transformers"]
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
print "Using Initial classifier"
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
for doc, category in zip(test_data, pred):
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, targets[category]))

# Training with updated training set
x = ["cricket", "Transformers is a film","which college"]
y = np.array([2,1,0])
X_train = vectorizer.transform(x)
clf.partial_fit(X_train, y)

# Testing with the updated trainign set
test_data = ["android","lenovo","Transformers"]
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
print "\nUsing Updatable classifiers"
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
for doc, category in zip(test_data, pred):
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, targets[category]))
```

The Output to this is

```
Using Initial classifier
'android' => phones
'lenovo' => laptops
'Transformers' => education

Using Updatable classifiers
'android' => sports
'lenovo' => education
'Transformers' => film
```

I have two questions onto this ->

1) the category for "lenovo" is coming wrong because training data for that category is not included while updating classifier. Is there any solution to avoid this. As I dont want to provide training data for each category every time I update the classifier. So It should work even if I provide the data for single category while updating.

2) how can I add new categories to the existing classifier. Like if I want a new category like "health" to the existing classifier. Then is there any way to do that.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you have an answer to the question @Gunjan ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `fit` for the first batch, call `partial_fit` and give it a list of all classes in your problem as the `classes` argument:

```
clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=targets)
```

(This is assuming `y` actually contains the class labels instead of their indices.)

You cannot change the number of classes after the first call to `partial_fit` (or `fit`). You simply have to know the number of classes up front or retrain the whole model.

Comment: i tried changing the first fit method to clf.partial_fit(X_train, y, classes=[0,1,2,3,4]) but still the laptops is getting classified under education after the update. So you also suggesting that we cant add a new class after first fit.

Comment: @Gunjan You're probably seeing a hash collision because `n_features` is too small in the vectorizer. Try setting it to a larger value.

Comment: tried that one..but doesnt seem to work either. Thanks though :)